# Chevy Cobalt engine replacement cost

Tags: engine, chevrolet

Replacing 2.0 engine. Just basic no cruise or power. Wondering how many hours by the book. Being charged $400 labor, $454 misc. Parts, $1100 for engine with 75000 miles

Comment: That seems very fair. I'd examine the misc. parts a little... but the labor cost is fair.

Comment: That's a pretty reasonable price. Also, how many miles / km on the car, and how many on the engine they're proposing? And, did you mean a Chevy Cobalt? I haven't heard of a Colbert, and neither, apparently, has Google.

Comment: i dont see how this is off topic. He is not asking for "shopping assistance". The "book hours" question has been deemed on-topic in the past

Comment: A guy was asking for advice on what size flue to use on his wood burning stove that he put in his van. That was on topic... this... obviously not.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling and replacing an engine is at least a days work for one mechanic (depending on what other work is also required), so if you pay $50/hr, you're getting a good deal. If their rate is higher, you're getting a great deal.

I'd want to know what the 'misc parts' covers - if it's just stuff like oil, coolant, filters etc, then that's a little high. If it covers a complete reseal and refurbishment of the replacement engine, then that's another good price.

Check the warranty on the replacement engine; many companies who sell warrantied used engines require the installer to replace certain parts (e.g timing belt/idlers/water pump) before their warranty is valid - and even if not required, doing that work is recommended anyway. It's a lot easier to replace that stuff *before* the engine goes back in.